# MEAN stack angular controller not defined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, express, mean-stack

I'm having a lot of trouble finding out why my controller isn't defined in my MEAN stack.  Every other controller is working just fine.

```
Error: Argument 'ReportsController' is not a function, got undefined
at assertArg (http://localhost:3000/lib/angular/angular.js:1039:11)
at assertArgFn (http://localhost:3000/lib/angular/angular.js:1049:3).....
```

app.js

```
window.app = angular.module('mean', ['ngCookies', 'ngResource', 'ui.bootstrap', 'ui.route', 'mean.system', 'mean.articles', 'mean.reports', 'angularFileUpload']);

angular.module('mean.system', []);
angular.module('mean.articles', []);
angular.module('mean.songs', []);
angular.module('mean.reports', []);
```

reports.js

```
angular.module('mean.reports').
controller('ReportsController',
    ['$scope', '$routeParams', '$location', 'Global', 'Reports',
        function ($scope, $routeParams, $location, Global, Reports) {
            $scope.global = Global;
            $scope.find = function() {
                    Reports.query(function(reports) {
                        $scope.reports = reports;
                    }
                );
            };
        }
    ]
);
```

routes.js

```
    //report routes
var reports = require('../app/controllers/reports');
app.get('/reports', reports.all);
app.post('/reports', auth.requiresLogin, reports.create);
app.get('/reports/:reportId', reports.show);
app.put('/reports/:reportId', auth.requiresLogin, auth.report.hasAuthorization, reports.update);
app.del('/reports/:reportId', auth.requiresLogin, auth.report.hasAuthorization, reports.destroy);


//Finish with setting up the reportId param
app.param('reportId', reports.report);
```

EDIT: Fixed - see comment

Comment: Apparently I didn't add the application service and controller to my 'foot.jade' file.  THAT FIXED EVERYTHING

Comment: Without changes for controller code?

Comment: Yeah, I didn't need to change the controller code

Answer (score 1):

You got that error because your controller definition in `reports.js` has errors: missing concluding `)`, `}`, `]`...

Because of that it is not recognized as a function by angular function `assertArg()` which throws the error.

It should be something like (I unfold it to get errors easier):

```
angular.module('mean.reports').
    controller('ReportsController', 
        ['$scope', '$routeParams', '$location', 'Global', 'Reports', 
            function ($scope, $routeParams, $location, Global, Reports) {
                $scope.global = Global;
                $scope.find = function() {
                    Reports.query(function(reports) {
                            $scope.reports = reports;
                        }
                    ); // <-- missing
                }; // <-- missing
            } // <-- misssing
        ] // <-- missing
    );
    }; // is seems that should be deleted
```

Each opening `(`, `[`, or `{` should be properly closed by `)`, `]`, or `}`.

Comment: I unfolded it for you - it is the same as your code except I don't have the extra bracket at the end.  I'm still getting the same error